# Difference in iterating over value type for std::map vs std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

The following program iterates over an `unordered_map` trying to find the best element but doesn't quite return the expected result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    int val;
};

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, Item> itemMap;
    itemMap[0] = {0};
    itemMap[1] = {1};
    itemMap[2] = {2};
    itemMap[3] = {3};
    const Item* bestItem = nullptr;
    int bestVal = -1;
    for (const pair<int, Item>& item : itemMap)
    {
        if (item.second.val > bestVal)
        {
            bestVal = item.second.val;
            bestItem = &item.second;
        }
    }
    cout << "best val: " << bestVal << " best item: " << bestItem->val;
    return 0;
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/pMUKa7)

Running this program prints out:

`best val: 3 best item: 0`

This seems to occur because the `value_type` of a `unordered_map` is [`std::pair<const Key, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) but we are iterating over `const pair<int, Item>`. Sure enough changing this to `const pair<const int, Item>` results in:

`best val: 3 best item: 3`

However if we change the type of `itemMap` to `std::map`:

`map<int, Item> itemMap`

Then it doesn't matter if we iterate over `const pair<int, Item>` or `const pair<const int, Item>` we get the same result:

`best val: 3 best item: 3`

Even though the `value_type` of `std::map` is still [`std::pair<const Key, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). But why?

Comment: Incidentally this seems to be a good reason to always write for loops as `for (auto&& : container)`.

Comment: @sjdownling in fact, [`for (auto const& el : container)`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dTeKf5Oek2c#t=2832)

Comment: @sehe Probably yes, I was thinking of STL's [proposed `for(elem : range)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question boils down to "Why does undefined behaviour gives different results for different containers?", to which the answer is "Because it's undefined".

Less flippantly: you're probably seeing the value from the final iteration, which will be the largest in the case of an ordered `map`, but could be anything in an `unordered_map`.

From your description, I guess you understand why it's undefined: a `const` reference can bind to a temporary, so if the type doesn't match exactly, it will do that rather than binding to the map element itself. The reference, and hence the temporary, is scoped within the loop, so isn't available outside. Your dangling pointer to it will end up pointing to whatever has reused that memory - in this case, that's most likely the same variable in a later iteration of the loop.

As you say in a comment, use `auto &&` (or, perhaps better, `auto const &`) so that type deduction makes sure the types match and the reference binds directly to the map element. Then the pointer will point to a map element, and will still be valid outside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Both your tests (with `unordered_map` and `map`) are exhibiting undefined behavior. The fact that one seems to work while the other doesn't is accidental, probably because they are iterated in a different order. Putting different values in the map will lead to it failing with `std::map` as well.

The reason the behavior is undefined: As you said the type of `item` is different from the `value_type` of the map. Because of this, a temporary of type `pair<int, Item>` is created and `item` (which is a const reference) is bound to this temporary. The lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of `item`.

Your `bestItem` pointer points to this temporary, but by the time you access it its lifetime has expired so the behavior is undefined.

If `item` is of a matching type (`const pair<const int, Item>&`), no temporary needs to be created as it can reference the map's `value_type` directly. `bestItem` is therefore a pointer into the map and everything works correctly.

Comment: This implicit conversion is _terrible_!